# Smart Algorithm for Remote Server Synchronization with local DB (Caching) in Android with pagination for offline support

Tags: android, algorithm, caching, pagination, synchronization

A very basic setup for offline support in the app where data fetched from the API is stored in Sq-lite for showing the lists when the app is not connected to internet.

The problem arises when I want to update the data in the DB with the data from the server. There is a predefined sorting order which is implemented on the server side and the data always comes in the same sequence.

On a fresh start the data is loaded and the it is saved on the DB in the sequence it is received and there is pagination implemented. Let's say after  some time data is refreshed and there are new items that are received in the Page 1 (1-10) and the Page 2 (11-20), but the DB has the 11-20 item as Page 1 because server added new items to this list and local doesn't have the newer items.

How do I handle this situation and properly save the newer 10 (or more/few) items so that when Page 1 is fetched from my DB then these new items are returned first and then the older ones? Basically how to handle the addition/deletion/modification of data in sync with the server.

I want to implement something like lot of the apps do such as Instagram/Facebook where you keep scrolling in the list as soon as you launch the app, make the network call in background, save the proper result to the DB and notify user that new items are added and scroll the list to the top to show the newer items.

I cannot use the latest Paging library and the other jet-pack components for this purpose as it will need an architecture level change in the app.

Answer (score 0):

I would timestamp the items when inserted into the local DB. Then when fetching pages other than the first page, also ask for items timestamped since the last fetch, in sorted order. Merge these in with the results for the second page.